# How to resolve asp.net's local database : "a network-related or instance-specific error occurred" error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to learn asp.net and database programming and so I tried to follow this tutorial [Asp.net Social Networking Site Tutorial](http://20fingers2brains.blogspot.com/2013/02/social-networking-website-in-aspnet.html) . The problem is that I created everything but when I try to register(by clicking register button) into this site, my details are not getting added to the database table, but I am not getting any exception or anything. But when I use same credentials ,that I used to register, to login, I am getting this error.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I am using user controls and here is my code behind for register page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string DOB = ddlDay.SelectedValue + " " + ddlMonth.SelectedValue + " " + ddlYear.SelectedValue;
        byte[] profilePicBytes = null;
        if (uploadPhoto.HasFile)
        {
            int length = uploadPhoto.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            profilePicBytes = new byte[length];
            HttpPostedFile img = uploadPhoto.PostedFile;
            img.InputStream.Read(profilePicBytes, 0, length);

            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Database.connString);
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Register (ProfilePic,Name,EmailId,Pwd,Gender,DOB,AboutMe,Country) VALUES (@ProfilePic,@Name,@Email,@Pwd,@Gender,@DOB,@AboutMe,@Country)", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProfilePic", SqlDbType.Image).Value = profilePicBytes;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtName.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtEmail.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pwd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtPassword.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = ddlGender.SelectedItem.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = DOB;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@AboutMe", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = txtAboutMe.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtCountry.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                Alert.Show("Registration Done Successfully");
                clearControls();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

    private void clearControls()
    {
        txtName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtEmail.Text = string.Empty;
        txtAboutMe.Text = string.Empty;
        txtCountry.Text = string.Empty;
        ddlGender.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ddlDay.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ddlMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ddlYear.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

When I click register, I want the filled details to be added to my database.
This is my partial database structure for where the register details must be added.

[image]

This is my connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Avaton" connectionString="Data Source=localhost; 
        Initial Catalog=AvatonDB;Integrated Security=True;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Here Avaton is the name of my project.

I have also attached all other files from my project here. I just want them to be added to my local database.
[My Entire Project](https://www.mediafire.com/?vk9ihbig2urfhpk)

Comment: Can you change `Data Source` with your current computer name or instance name? If target DB has password protected credential(s), also provide your user name and password on DB connection string, or use Server Explorer to generate it.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server installed on your computer? If not you are either going to need to install it (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42299). Once you have that installed then EF should create the database for you.